# Bash and sh returns same version, so whats the difference

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I was trying to find version of different shell on my machine, but found to be the same.

```
sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.


bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How can they point to save version?

Comment: Off-topic for SO, but the short answer is that `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are implemented as the same program on your system. Bash detects how you invoke it and acts more POSIX-y when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` has some abilities that `sh` would consider
[to be unnatural](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)

```
$ bash -c 'cat <(pwd)'
/home/Steven

$ sh -c 'cat <(pwd)'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(pwd)'
```

Comment: Correct, bash provides many abilities. So its better to use bash.